# Avoiding partially implemented trait in API design

Tags: rust

When trying to model some problems as traits, I run into cases where a partial implementation of a trait seems to be needed. Is there an approach for reworking these cases, or `panic!`-ing when the not implemented parts are required at runtime?

For example, imagine a simple IO trait for reading audio samples.

A `Sample` can be either scalar (`i32` or `u32`) or floating point (`f32` or `f64`). Furthermore we want an API that lets us read raw data (`u8`) so each sample type must also contain `u8`.

The `IO` trait will have a function like `fn read(&mut self) -> Vec<T>` where `T: Sample`.

We then implement some IO strategies, `ScalarIOStrategy` and `FloatingIOStrategy` to read files of those sample types.

How can we write a factory method `fn build_io_strategy(is_scalar: bool) -> Box<dyn IO<T>>` that can try to construct either the scalar or floating strategy depending on the argument and the generic type? Is there an alternative pattern that fits the rust type system better?

This code shows the general problem [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=8506f92d90814a3760a81b7bbf88dcb8)

```rust
use std::any::TypeId;
use std::marker::PhantomData;

trait Sample {}
impl Sample for u8 {}
impl Sample for i32 {}
impl Sample for u32 {}
impl Sample for f32 {}
impl Sample for f64 {}

trait Scalar : Sample {}
impl Scalar for u8 {}
impl Scalar for i32 {}
impl Scalar for u32 {}

trait Floating : Sample {}
impl Floating for u8 {}
impl Floating for f32 {}
impl Floating for f64 {}

trait SampleIO<T: Sample> {
    fn do_io(&mut self) -> Vec<T> { Vec::new() }
}

struct ScalarIOStrategy<T: Scalar> {
    _phantom: PhantomData<T>
}

impl<T: Scalar> SampleIO<T> for ScalarIOStrategy<T> {}

struct FloatingIOStrategy<T: Floating> {
    _phantom: PhantomData<T>
}

impl<T: Floating> SampleIO<T> for FloatingIOStrategy<T> {}

fn build_io_strategy<T: Sample>(is_scalar: bool) -> Box<dyn SampleIO<T>> {
    let tid = TypeId::of::<T>();
    
    if is_scalar {
        if TypeId::of::<i32>() == tid || TypeId::of::<u32>() == tid || TypeId::of::<u8>() == tid {
            Box::new(ScalarIOStrategy::<T> { _phantom: PhantomData })
        } else {
            panic!("Invalid type")
        }
    } else {
        if TypeId::of::<f32>() == tid || TypeId::of::<f64>() == tid || TypeId::of::<u8>() == tid {
            Box::new(FloatingIOStrategy::<T> { _phantom: PhantomData })
        } else {
            panic!("Invalid type")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You can write a default method implementation that panics using [`unimplemented!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.unimplemented.html)

Comment: I think `build_io_strategy` should be part of the `Sample` trait, that way when implementing the method you do have access to the concrete type, not just a type variable.

Comment: That seems like a great idea, but I think there's a problem. `build_io_strategy` would return `Box<SampleIO<Self>>`, but the two possible IO strategies for it to return are `ScalarIOStrategy<T: Scalar>` and `FloatingIOStrategy<T: Floating>`. Even though `Scalar` is-a `Sample` I don't think Rust will allow that conversion.

Comment: Well you'd be [wrong to think that](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a744b287e18694fc7faac555f29a7f36) because `SampleIO` only needs `T: Sample`

Comment: Yes, I was just trying that. It certainly seems like it solves my problem provided the strategies are all in the same crate. I'm trying to see now if I can use some kind of static registry of builder methods to keep the strategy objects fully decoupled from the `Sample` trait.

Comment: No need to be in the same crate, you can implement `Sample` or maybe a more generic `IoStrategyBuilder` from everywhere.